# Objective-C : Issue faced while editing multiple row simultaneously in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I am doing chat application. Some what I did with all major functionalities. Now I am having doubt on multiple selection row and edit it. I am having issue on following two things:

**1.** If I tried to edit my chat table view, cells are moving towards right. My chat messages are hiding partially.

**2.** If I select that round button, some color appearing on my cell. That color hiding my view color. I dont know how to clear that color.

Kindly guide me for this following two things.

**My Output:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
- (IBAction)cellLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{

    [_tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

In WhatsApp, one side cell is moving towards right, and another remains constant. How to do that?

How to clear that deletion dim color?

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

**1.** Which cell we dont want to indent, add below code on our tableviewcell subclass

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    float indentPoints = self.indentationLevel * self.indentationWidth;

    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints,
                                        self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.height);
}
```

**2.Color hiding my view color**

**In Cell for Row Index Path**

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [_myChatCell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
return _myChatCell;
    }
```

**Set Selected**

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if(selected) {
_message.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
} else {
_message.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
}
```